# XTerm fonts' size reduced after system update

Tags: x11, opensuse, fonts, high-dpi

This notebook has a 185 dpi display, but I have followed the guidelines for [High DPI](https://en.opensuse.org/High_DPI) and everything was, more or less, fine.

Today I updated the system (`sudo zypper update`) and after a reboot the characters in every XTerm are way too small, while the characters in all the other applications I have opened are OK with respect to character size.

I've found something suspicious in the output of `xdpyinfo`

```
21:41 boffi@localhost:~ $ xdpyinfo | grep inch
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
21:41 boffi@localhost:~ $
```

but I'm not sure that before the reboot the resolution was correct.

Any suggestion?

---

Post Scriptum

```
21:43 boffi@localhost:~ $ xrandr --dpi 185
```

fixes the issue, but there is a way to have `Xorg` started with the correct resolution?

---

PPost Scriptum

```
22:05 boffi@localhost:~ $ xrdb -q | grep -i dpi
Xft.dpi:        175
22:06 boffi@localhost:~ $
```

On the other hand, XTerm *should* also depend on this value.

Comment: [Known bug/fix](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1021243).

Comment: @ThomasDickey The bug you mentioned is about `Xft.dpi` treatment? (please see my last edit in the question)

Comment: The issue was omitting the data set via `xrdb` on the X server (`Xft.dpi` is one part of that).  The bug report shows the fix, which will be in #374.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thank you for the clarification. Fortunately, the `xrandr` workaround I've mentioned works fine…